# wordpress plugin development page form is being displayed at the bottom of every post and page edit

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

I am developing a wordpress CRUD plugin for a custom data table and it is working pretty well. However the page form that is used in the plugin for inserting or editing new records is also being displayed at the bottom of all page and post new page/post and edit page/post within the admin area.

[Screenshot of page html from plugin displaying at the bottom of the add new page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lkvD.jpg)

The other pages within the plugin do not display anywhere else within wordpress as expected. I am completely lost to what I have done incorrectly and hope that someone can point me in the right direction to resolving this.

If I deactivate the plugin the issue remains.

I have used the boilerplate template as a base for developing the plugin found here:

[https://wppb.me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lkvD.jpg)

This is adding the menu option and callback for it:

```
    $sub2_cb = array(&$this,'new_award_category_page');     // callback function. name

        add_submenu_page( 
            'Settings', 
            'Award Categories Add New', 
            'Add New', 
            'manage_options',
            'add-category',
            $sub2_cb
         );
```

Here is the callback function that includes the page:

```
    public function new_award_category_page() {
    include_once( 'partials/new-award-category-page.php' );     
}
```

The same page is being called from the row edit links in a wp_list_table for edits to existing records:

```
function column_category($item){

    //Build row actions
    $actions = array(
        'edit' => sprintf('<a href="?page=add-category&id=%s">%s</a>', $item['id'], __('Edit', 'new_award_category_page')),
    );

    //Return the title contents
    return sprintf('%1$s <span style="color:silver"></span>%3$s',
        /*$1%s*/ $item['category'],
        /*$2%s*/ $item['id'],
        /*$3%s*/ $this->row_actions($actions)
    );
}
```

Here is the include file with the page php/html to check if insert or update new record, validation and display the form (split into sections to put in here):

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name =  'wp_categories'; // do not forget about tables prefix

$message = '';
$notice = '';

// this is default $item which will be used for new records
$default = array(
    'id' => null,
    'category' => '',
    'paragraph_1' => '',
    'paragraph_2' => '',
    'img' => '',
    'manager' => ''
);

// here we are verifying does this request is post back and have correct nonce
if (wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
    // combine our default item with request params
    $item = shortcode_atts($default, $_REQUEST);
    // validate data, and if all ok save item to database
    // if id is zero insert otherwise update
    $item_valid = award_category_validate($item);
    if ($item_valid === true) {
        if ($item['id'] == 0) {
            $result = $wpdb->insert($table_name, $item);
            $item['id'] = $wpdb->insert_id;
            if ($result) {
                $message = __('Item was successfully saved', 'new_award_category_page');
            } else {
                $notice = __('There was an error while saving item', 'new_award_category_page');
            }
        } else {
            $result = $wpdb->update($table_name, $item, array('id' => $item['id']));
            if ($result) {
                $message = __('Item was successfully updated', 'new_award_category_page');
            } else {
                $notice = __('There was an error while updating item', 'new_award_category_page');
            }
        }
    } else {
        // if $item_valid not true it contains error message(s)
        $notice = $item_valid;
    }
}
else {
    // if this is not post back we load item to edit or give new one to create
    $item = $default;
    if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
        $item = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id = %d", $_REQUEST['id']), ARRAY_A);
        if (!$item) {
            $item = $default;
            $notice = __('Item not found', 'new_award_category_page');
        }
    }
}
```

hhhh

```
function award_category_validate($item) {

$messages = array();

if (empty($item['category'])) $messages[] = __('Category title is required ', 'new_award_category_page');
if (empty($item['paragraph_1'])) $messages[] = __('Introductory paragraph is required', 'new_award_category_page');
if (empty($item['img'])) $messages[] = __('Representation image is required', 'new_award_category_page');

if (empty($messages)) return true;
return implode('<br />', $messages);
```

}

```html
div class="wrap">
 <h2><?php _e('Awards Entry Category Maintenenace', 'new_award_category_page')?></h2>

    <?php if (!empty($notice)): ?>
    <div id="notice" class="error"><p><?php echo $notice ?></p></div>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php if (!empty($message)): ?>
    <div id="message" class="updated"><p><?php echo $message ?></p></div>
    <?php endif;?>

 <div id="poststuff">
  <div id="post-body" class="metabox-holder columns-1">
   <div id="post-body-content">
    <div class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable">
     <form method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__))?>"/>
      <?php /* NOTICE: here we storing id to determine will be item added or updated */ ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $item['id'] ?>"/>
      
      <table class="form-table">
       <tr valign="top">
        <td scope="row"><label for="tablecell"><?php esc_attr_e('Category Title:', 'WpAdminStyle'); ?></label>
        </td>
        <td>
         <input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="<?php echo $item['category'] ?>" class="large-text" required />
        </td>
       </tr>   
       
       <tr valign="top">
        <td scope="row"><label for="tablecell"><?php esc_attr_e('Introductory Paragraph:', 'WpAdminStyle'); ?></label>
        </td>
        <td>
         <textarea id="" name="paragraph_1" cols="80" rows="8" class="large-text" required><?php echo $item['paragraph_1'] ?></textarea>
        </td>
       </tr>   

       <tr valign="top">
        <td scope="row"><label for="tablecell"><?php esc_attr_e('Supplimentary Paragraph:', 'WpAdminStyle'); ?></label>
        </td>
        <td>
         <textarea id="paragraph_2" name="paragraph_2" cols="80" rows="8" class="large-text"><?php echo $item['paragraph_2'] ?></textarea>
        </td>
       </tr>   
          
       <tr valign="top">
        <td scope="row"><label for="tablecell"><?php esc_attr_e('Category Representation Image:', 'WpAdminStyle'); ?> required></label>
        </td>
        <td>
         <input type="text" name="img" id="img" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo $item['img'] ?>">
         <input type="button" name="upload-btn" id="upload-btn" class="button-secondary" value="Upload Image" required>        
        </td>
       </tr> 

       <tr valign="top">
        <td scope="row">
        </td>
        <td>
         <img id="previewImg" src="<?php echo $item['img'] ?>" style="width:150px;height:auto;">          
        </td>
       </tr> 
         
       <tr valign="top">
        <td scope="row"><label for="tablecell"><?php esc_attr_e('Owner:', 'WpAdminStyle'); ?></label>
        </td>
        <td>
         <input type="text" name="manager" value="<?php echo $item['manager'] ?>" class="large-text" required />
        </td>
       </tr>  
           
       <tr valign="top">
        <td scope="row">        
        </td>
        <td>
         <div align="right">
          <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Save', 'new_award_category_page')?>" id="submit" class="button-primary" name="submit">
         </div>
        </td>
       </tr>      
      </table>      
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <br class="clear">
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is that HTML a theme file specific for the form page? Or is that a base template file?

Comment: It is part of the callback function for a page in the plugin, so is part of the plugin not the theme I had to split the callback function up in here into different code segments so it would display but is all one function within the plugin - the contents of partials/new-award-category-page.php